# Unable to get property of undefined or null reference IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've inherited a website with some funky code. It held together OK until IE 10 when it started to throw this error:

```
Unable to get property 'offsetHeight' of undefined or null reference Line: 27 Char: 1 Code: 0 UR
```

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function transDiv(){
var theheight=document.getElementById('transcontent').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('translayer').style.height=theheight+'px';
}
window.onload=transDiv;
setInterval("transDiv()",1); //this handles text resizing through the users browser
</script>
```

Any thoughts/assistance would be appreciated. Seems to work just fine in Chrome and FF and the client's version of IE (8, ugh).

Comment: It means that there's no element on the page whose "id" value is "transcontent".  Also that's just a terrible way of doing things; the website must really spin up some fans.

Comment: does `document.getElementById('transcontent')` return a valid node ?

Comment: Have you tried changing window.onload to document.onload? It's possible that the DOM hasn't been fully loaded/initialised yet.

Comment: @MattFletcher those are the same events.

Comment: `setInterval(…, 1)` is much too fast. I also is quite possible that the first invocation happens before document.ready…

Answer (score 1):

The elements don't have time to load in the 1 millisecond interval. You can change the code to this as a workaround to keep the exact same functionality:

```
function transDiv() {
    var content = document.getElementById('transcontent');
    var layer = document.getElementById('translayer');
    if (!content || !layer)
        return;
    var theheight = content.offsetHeight;
    layer.style.height=theheight+'px';
    window.setTimeout(transDiv, 1);
}
window.onload = transDiv;
```

However as it appears to be meant to handle resize, just catch the event instead of using timer. Get rid of the `window.setTimeout()` line and add this below the code:

```
window.onresize = transDiv;
```